# Click function is removing end of localStorage items not at Index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My current code adds and removes items from a list, then the user can save the list and I want the user to be able to remove items from the saved list, this is done through a function `removeItemsLocalStorage()` but what is happening is that the localStorage items are getting removed from the end and not at the index, I am a little confused as to how to get the index position of the localStorage items, which is an array. This is more of a learning exercise process for me.

Code is:

```
let domElements = {
    app: document.createElement('DIV'),
    heading: document.createElement('H1'),
    header: document.createElement('DIV'), 
    hero: document.createElement('DIV'),
    newDiv: document.createElement('DIV'),
    errorMessage: document.createElement('P'),
    grid: document.createElement('DIV'), 
    saveList: document.createElement('UL')
}

function domAttributes() {
    domElements.app.classList.add('app');
    document.body.append(domElements.app);
    domElements.heading.textContent = 'Shopping';
    domElements.newDiv.innerHTML = '<p>This is the text of the element</p>';
    domElements.heading.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", domElements.newDiv);
    domElements.errorMessage.innerHTML= 'Error type something in!';
    domElements.heading.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", domElements.errorMessage);
    domElements.errorMessage.style.color = 'red';
    domElements.errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
    domElements.app.append(domElements.heading);
    domElements.grid.classList.add('grid');
    domElements.saveList.classList.add('saveUl');
    domElements.app.append(domElements.grid);
}

domAttributes();

var data = [
    "Monday", 
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday"
];

let gridItems = [
    '<div id="item1" class="item"></div>',
    '<div id="item2" class="item"></div>'
];

var loopElement = 
    {
        image: `<div class="innerElement">Head Test</div>`,
        name: 'Element'
    };

function gridItemLooper(ele) {
    let items = ''; 
    for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        items += ele[i];
    }
    return items;
}

const gridInnerElement = gridItemLooper(gridItems);        
domElements.grid.innerHTML = gridInnerElement;  

function looper() {
let loopImage = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    loopImage += loopElement.image;
    }
    return loopImage;
}    


function heroElement() {
    domElements.hero.textContent = 'Hero';
    domElements.hero.classList.add('hero');
    domElements.hero.innerHTML = '<div class="innerElement">Inner Element</div>';
    domElements.hero.setAttribute(
     "style", "font-size: 32px; font-style: bold; background-color:#000000; color: white; width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 20px; font-family: sans-serif"); 
     domElements.app.append(domElements.hero);
}

function itemArray(ele) {
    let items = ''; 
    for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        items += `<li>${ele[i]} <button type='button' class='removeItem'>Remove Item</button> </li>`;
    }
    return items;
}

function layOut() {
    const ui = heroElement();
}

layOut();

function addItemFunction (ele) {
    const addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
    const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    
    if (input.length > 0 ) {
        data.push(input);  
        htmlInside(data); 
        domElements.errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        domElements.errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
    }
    
}

function removeItemFunction() {
    data.pop(data);    
    htmlInside(data);
}

function removeItems() {
    const listUl = domElements.app.querySelector('.listItems');
    listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
          let li = event.target.parentNode;
          let ul = li.parentNode;
          ul.removeChild(li);         
          var ele = li.textContent.split(" ")[0];
          var index = data.indexOf(ele);
          data.splice(index, 1);
          console.log(data); 
        }
      });
}

function removeItemsLocalStorage() {
    const listUl = domElements.app.querySelector('.saveUl');
    listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
          let li = event.target.parentNode;
          let ul = li.parentNode;
          ul.removeChild(li);
          let displayItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Shopping List"));
          var ele = li.textContent;
          var index = displayItems.indexOf(ele);
          alert(ele);
          displayItems.splice(index, 1);
          localStorage.setItem('Shopping List', JSON.stringify(displayItems));
        }
    });
}

domElements.app.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", domElements.saveList);
let displayItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Shopping List"));

if (localStorage.length > 0) {
    domElements.saveList.innerHTML = displayArray(displayItems);
}

function saveItems(ele) {
    localStorage.setItem('Shopping List', JSON.stringify(ele));
    let displayItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Shopping List"));
    domElements.saveList.innerHTML = displayArray(displayItems);
}

function clearItems(ele) {
    localStorage.clear(ele);
    domElements.saveList.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('Shopping List');
}

function displayArray(ele) {
    let items = ''; 
    for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        items += `<li>${ele[i]} <button type='button' class='removeItem'>Remove Item</button></li> `;
    }
    return items;
}

function clickEvents() {
    addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        addItemFunction();
    });

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        removeItemFunction();
    });
    
    saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        saveItems(data);
    });
    clearButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        clearItems(data);
    });
}

function htmlInside(data){
    let getHtml = `
        <ul class="listItems">
            ${itemArray(data)}    
        </ul>
        <input type='input' id='input'></input><button type='button' id='addButton'>Add item</button><button id='removeButton'>Remove item</button><button id='saveButton'>Save list</button><button id='clearButton'>clear list</button>
    `
    document.querySelector('.hero').innerHTML = getHtml;
    removeItems();
    clickEvents();
 }  
 
 htmlInside(data);
 removeItemsLocalStorage(data);
```

Comment: Whats the output of this one   => var index = displayItems.indexOf(ele);

Comment: Sorry its the text for the item i.e "Monday Remove Item"

Comment: @Sole yep so thats the issue, you are doing displayItems.splice(-1, 1); which will remove the last element , example snippet => let a = [1,2,3]; a.splice(-1, 1); console.log(a) // will be [1,2]

Comment: So what would be the better approach?

Comment: @Sole So in the above line => var index = displayItems.indexOf(ele); // which is checking whether the element is present there or not, so two output it will return ,inside the displayItems 1) if the element is present then the index of the element 2) if its not present then -1, as in your case.  According to your use case if the element is not there what will be the workflow, can you explain. I think may be you can add a if else condition to check and perform further.

Comment: @Sole Or we need to debug why we are getting -1, why => var ele = li.textContent;  ele is not present in displayItems ? let me know some details as i didn't completely understood the workflow

Answer (score 0):

In the end this code below worked, I had to use the `split()` method.

```
function removeItemsLocalStorage() {
    const listUl = domElements.app.querySelector('.saveUl');
    listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
          let li = event.target.parentNode;
          let ul = li.parentNode;
          ul.removeChild(li);
          let displayItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Shopping List"));
          var ele = li.textContent.split(" ")[0];
          var index = displayItems.indexOf(ele);
          displayItems.splice(index, 1);
          localStorage.setItem('Shopping List', JSON.stringify(displayItems));
        }
    });
}
```